# How to do remote debugging with Eclipse CDT without gdbserver?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging, aix

We're using the Eclipse CDT 5 C++ IDE on Windows to develop a C++ application on a remote AIX host.

Eclipse CDT has the ability to perform remote debugging using gdbserver. Unfortunately, gdbserver is not supported on AIX.

Is anyone familiar with a way to debug remotely using Eclipse CDT without gdbserver? Perhaps using an SSH shell connection to gdb?

Comment: With `gdbserver`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685104/remote-debugging-c-applications-with-eclipse-cdt-rse-rdt/45658783#45658783

Comment: Check out BVRDE - an IDE for remote debugging (works without gdbserver): https://sourceforge.net/projects/bvrde/

Answer (score 11):

finally I got gdb run remotly anyhow now. At the Bug-symbol on the taskbar I took Debug Configurations - GDB Hardware Debugging.

In Main C/C++ Applications I set the full path on the Samba share of the executable (`X:\abin\vlmi9506`). I also set a linked folder on `X:\abin` in the project. Then I modified my batch-script in GDB Setup. It's not directly calling gdb in the plink-session but a unix-shell-script, which opens gdb. By this I have the possibility to set some unix environment-variables for the program before doing debug. The call in my batch:

```
plink.exe prevoax1 -l suttera -pw XXXXX -i /proj/user/dev/suttera/vl/9506/test/vlmi9506ddd.run 20155 dev o m
```

In the unix script I started gdb with the command line params from eclipse, that I found in my former tryals. The call in the shell command looks like this:

```
gdb -nw -i mi -cd=$LVarPathExec $LVarPathExec/vlmi9506
```

Then IBM just gives gdb 6.0 for AIX. I found version 6.8 in the net at http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Gdb. Our Admin installed it.

I can now step through the program and watch variables. I even can write gdb-commands directly in the console-view. yabadabadooooooo

Hope that helps to others as well. Can not tell, what was really the winner-action.
But each answer gives more new questions. Now I got 3 of them.

1. When I start the debug config I have to click restart in the toolbar to come really in the main procedure. Is it possible to come directly in main without restarting?
2. On AIX our programs are first preprocessed for embedded sql. The preprocessed c-source is put in another directory. When I duble-click the line to set a breakpoint, I get the warning "unresolved breakpoint" and in the gdb-console I see, that the break is set to the preprocessed source which is wrong. Is it possible to set the breakpoints on the right source?
3. We are using CICS on AIX. With the xldb-Debugger and the CDCN-command of CICS we manage that debugging is started, when we come in our programs. Is it possible to get that remotely (in plink) with gdb-eclipse as well?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't normally take a shot in the dark on a question I can't really test the answer to, but since this one has sat around for a day, I'll give it a shot.  It seems from looking at:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ#How_can_I_do_Remote_Debugging_with_CDT.3F

...that even if the CDT has changed since that wiki page was made, you should still be able to change the debug command to:

ssh remotehost gdb

instead of using TM which uses gdbserver.  This will probably be slightly slower than the TM remote debugging since that actually uses a local gdb, but on the other hand this way you won't have to NFS or SMB mount your source code to make it available to the local debugger (and if you're on a LAN it probably won't matter anyhow).

There's also a reference TCF implementation for linux, which you may or may not have any luck recompiling for AIX, but it allows for remote debugging if gdbserver is otherwise not available:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/DSDP/TM/TCF_FAQ

Answer (score 0):

tried also to remotly debug an aix-appl with windows eclipse-cdt-gdb.
Got blocked at the end with unix/windows path-problems. Maybe my result can help u a little further - maybe you already got it work. I'm interested in your comment. asked on eclipse news portal- following the answer of martin oberhuber (thanks again) tried dsp dd (also blocked with path problem) and set an request in eclipse bugzilla.

here the link to news: 
http://www.eclipse.org/newsportal/article.php?id=406&group=eclipse.dsdp.tm
Here my bugzilla:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=252758

At the moment we still debug localy with xldb but I am trying ddd-gdb at the moment. At least locally gdb is running.