# How to debug a linux C++ program from Windows with Eclipse?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb

I use a headless (i.e. no screen) remote ubuntu server x64 for developping a C++ application (with no UI either).

I want to conveniently (IDE like, not command line) debug this program from windows (7/64), with Eclipse if possible. I have a windows share between the two and full root access on both machines.

So far I have heard of two solutions :

1. Remote gdb
2. Remote X server

I have worked on solution 1 : built a cross gdb, copied my program and libs on windows. I'm able to remote-gdb from cygwin command line, but not from eclipse (stuck at "launching... 85%" with no error message nor log)

I have also worked on solution 2 : installed xauth, set X forwarding, installed xming on my windows, set DISPLAY on the linux box. But no effect "can't open DISPLAY xxx" with no easy troubleshoot.

When googling for those problems, I only find outdated pages or different problems.

Did anyone do it ? Can you share advices or fresh pointers on how to remote debug a C++ linux app from Windows ?

Comment: can't you ssh into the machine and start gdb there?

Comment: Use Emacs with tramp plug-in?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Of course, I have full root access to the linux server. I want convenient _graphical_ debug, not command-line gdb.

Comment: I can't think of any way you can debug ubuntu software using a windows GUI.....

Comment: @Offirmo: X forwarding should work. Could you please post what you did for solution 2?

Comment: already bean discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81194/remote-debugging-with-eclipse-cdt

Comment: @Lol4t0 thanks. As I said, seems outdated (2008/2009) I'll have a look anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to install an [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server on your Windows machine (e.g. [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) perhaps?) and to do `ssh -X` with some X11 client applications (like `emacs`, `ddd` if needed, `xterm`) on your Linux server. Don't use a complex thing like Eclipse. You could just use `emacs` (remotely on the Linux server, displaying on the Windows desktop X11 server)...

Once `emacs` works well (running on the remote Linux server, displaying on the Windows desktop X11 server), you can run `gdb` inside it.

To get `ssh -X` working, you need to configure it appropriately. Maybe you forgot that step. To test it, just use `ssh -X yourlinuxhost xterm`, and work on configuration till that step works.

Of course you could also install Linux on your laptop or desktop, perhaps inside a virtual machine above your Windows.

NB. I never used Windows, but I do know that some X11 servers exist for it.

Comment: It works now. The only thing I was missing was telling xming to accept connections from everyone with -ac. I was able to run the full fledged Eclipse and debug my program. Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure that you need `-ac` (which I guess is same as `xhost +` on Unix). Perhaps some `ssh` (AKA `putty` on Windows) trick could do ... I have no idea which trick on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a eclipse plugin [RSE](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/tutorial/index.php) (Remote System Explorer), it can pretty much do what you are expecting. The code base can be in  linux server, eclipses uses telnet / ssh to login. Execution again can happen on a server, native gdb is used to debug.

Comment: Emacs does the same, and this feature is there way before Eclipse existed.

Comment: This is exactly what I use. And it doesn't work. Stuck at 85% while launching the debug configuration. No error message, no log. Do you have a link to a tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following simple plugin for Eclipse.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/direct-remote-c-debugging

It needs just ssh connection to the server and it cares about anything else