# Eclipse cdt remote build and remote debug on different servers

Tags: linux, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

There are similar questions about that but I couldn't find this specific scenario :

Computer A - Linux build server

Computer B - Linux debug server

Computer C - Windows, my local comp.

I have a c/c++ project -eclipse cdt. Can I edit the source file on Computer C, build on Computer A and transfer to Computer B, then debug it via my local project? How can I do this with existing tools/config with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

As a first step you might want to try gdbserver: [Remote debugging with Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81194/remote-debugging-with-eclipse-cdt) or [Better variable exploring when debugging C++ code with Eclipse/CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651862/better-variable-exploring-when-debugging-c-code-with-eclipse-cdt) or [Eclipse cdt remote build and remote debug on different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918919/eclipse-cdt-remote-build-and-remote-debug-on-different-servers) offer advice on that.

Depending on your linux distribution, a [hudson](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/) server can be set up as Computer B.
Hudson supports 
 - Ubuntu, Debian, Oracle Enterprise Linux, RedHat, CentOS, Fedora, openSUSE
as can be seen [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Hudson-ci/Using_Hudson/Installing_Hudson).

Hudson has been developed in Java, but it is language agnostic, so it works for C as well.

In general, you can commit your changes (from Comp A directly or to a central Git Server) and Hudson (running on Comp B) will build it and deliver it to your debug server (Comp C), on which you are running GDB.

I lack experience with CDT, so I can't give you a more detailed instruction on how to set it all up apart from linking to manuals. And you'd have to test if GDB supports the Windows/Linux mix.